# change MKCircle Radius with UI Slider dynamically

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

i'm working on a project right now with MapView. You can Drop a pin by Tab and hold. And when you select the pin a circle with a certain radius will appear. But now the user should decide what radius the circle will have. This should be possible by a UISlider.

The problem is, that the circle radius does not change dynamically. the circle appears, you move the slider and nothing happens. Deselecting and selecting the pin again, will add another ring with the new UISlider Value.

Current code:
in .h file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) MKCircle *pinCircle;
```

in .m file:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    _radius.hidden= false;

    CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[(MKPointAnnotation*)[view annotation] coordinate].latitude longitude:[(MKPointAnnotation*)[view annotation] coordinate].longitude];
    _pinCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:pinLocation.coordinate radius:_radius.value*1000];
    [_mapView addOverlay:_pinCircle];
    [_pinCircle autorelease];

}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    _radius.hidden= true;
    }

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    return [circleView autorelease];
}
```

i know i have to use this action:

```
- (IBAction)radiusSliderChange:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Slidervalue changed");
    [self.pinCircle removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But this causes the following error:

```
-[MKCircle removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18b919d0
```

According to the Post of Alejandro F. Carrera  i got the following Errors:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/saxhns992jex606/Bildschirmfoto%202014-09-04%20um%2020.20.21.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You must set to nil at init (pinCircle = nil;) then you must check this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
   if(pinCircle != nil) // click two annotations
   {
      [_mapView removeOverlay: _pinCircle];
       _pinCircle = nil;
   }
   _radius = 100; // start value to define
   [self createCircle: view.annotation.coordinate];
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
{
    if(pinCircle != nil)
    {
       [_mapView removeOverlay: _pinCircle];
       _pinCircle = nil;
    }
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    return [circleView autorelease];
}
```

You have used Storyboard for this so, you must have slider variable like pinCircle

```
- (IBAction)radiusSliderChange:(id)sender {
    _radius = _slider.value;  // radius property of circle is readonly so you must create other one
    [_mapView removeOverlay: _pinCircle];
    [self createCircle:_pinCircle.coordinate];
}

- (void)createCircle:(CLLocationCoordinate)coord
{
    _pinCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coord radius:_radius.value*1000];
    [_mapView addOverlay:_pinCircle];
    [_pinCircle autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. your answer gives my multiple errors i can't deal with. i posted them above

Comment: This is generally the right idea but I think you may have used the OP's existing variable names in a different and confusing way.  For example, _radius in the question is the UISlider itself.  Another potential problem is in the memory management and referring to pinCircle/_pinCircle (self.pinCircle would be preferred).  It would also be good to point out that one should use the new rendererForOverlay delegate method instead as well as switching to ARC.

Comment: I use the same notation of post. Of course, it is better use private or property variables and use ARC for Memory Management. It is only aproximation for author. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can adress your MKCircle *pinCircle in .h file and than access it like "self.pinCircle". After that, you'll be able to use `[self.pinCircle removeFromSuperview];` to delete it.. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i get the following error. See my edit above.

Comment: To remove all pins on map, you can use [mapView removeOverlays:[mapView overlays]]; Try it :-)

Comment: thanks @stepik21 i was trying to re create fence circle using slider ..your line of code works fine **[mapView removeOverlays:[mapView overlays]];** votingup your comment thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove previously added overlays after slider value changed.

```
  - (IBAction)sliderForJixRadiusValueChanged:(id)sender {
    //    self.mapSelectorManager.circleRadius = self.sliderForJixRadius.value;

        [_mapView removeOverlays:arrOverlay];

        MKCircle *circle= [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:_droppedAt1 radius: (_sliderForJixRadius.value)*10000];
        [_mapView addOverlay:circle];
        [arrOverlay addObject:circle];
```